# Creating a bargraph from binary variables

Tags: r

I have specific journals and their titles and the presence of whether or not a specific program was used. If the program was used, it is coded as a 1. If the program was not used, it is coded as a 0. How can I best create this into a bar graph?

Here is a really simple dataframe of the data.

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(Journal.Name = c("Journal1", "Journal2", "Journal3", 
"Journal4", "Journal5", "Journal6", "Journal7", "Journal8", "Journal9", 
"Journal10", "Journal11"), Title = c("Paper1", "Paper2", "Paper3", 
"Paper4", "Paper5", "Paper6", "Paper7", "Paper8", "Paper9", "Paper10", 
"Paper11"), R = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), Python = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    MatLab = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), SPSS = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

I'm thinking that the bar graph will have frequency on the y-axis and the specific types of programs on the x-axis. I don't care really about the journal or title.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```r
barplot(colSums(test[, -(1:2)]==1))
```

[image: barplot]